# Android: How can i listen to all notifications and incoming calls?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an app and i want it to listen to all notifications (like messages from various apps), and incoming calls how can i do it?

Comment: You'll have to list them all in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are broadcast receivers for such situations. For example here's an example of how to listen for the incoming call broadcast. [Broadcast Receiver For New Incomming Phone Call - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86)

Answer (score 0):

Using **NotificationListenerService** we can able to listen all notification and incoming calls.

```
   public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;


        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);

    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

Check complete tutorial and demo code **[here](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html)**